# Enabling and Disabling a trigger in a Postgres function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I have a trigger on a table and I want to catch the messages that are introduced between an interval. I had created a function who recive an integer() as a parameter.

The pseudocode  is something like this:

```
alter table <table_name> enable trigger <trigger_name>;
PERFORM pg_sleep(<nrofseconds>);
alter table <table_name> disable trigger <trigger_name>;
```

The problem is that, a Postgres function works as a single transaction and the trigger is enabled, then disabled at the end of execution, when commit is called so it does not track anything.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You cannot do that in a function, as you found out. So you should do it in client code, like a `psql` script or something else.

Comment: Yeah. I found a workaround. I split the function in 2 so it can commit after enable and from interface I call them 1 by 1